# How to write a JOIN condition (with the USING clause)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to compare two columns with the same name from two different tables but I keep getting errors.

Is there a way to do the expressions without "public" and without the double quotes `""`?

```
SELECT "OrderNr"
FROM public."Export"
LEFT JOIN public."Temp"
USING "Export"."OrderNr" = "Temp"."OrderNr";
```

Comment: You can only get rid of the double quotes if you re-create your tables without them.  https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: Well, what indeed is the error you are getting and is it related to the presence of double quotes ?

Answer (score 2):

Your JOIN syntax is wrong. As the column `"OrderNr"` is present in both tables, you also need to qualify the table from which you want to take it in the SELECT list. Using a table alias makes this easier.

```
SELECT e."OrderNr"
FROM public."Export" e
  LEFT JOIN public."Temp" t ON e."OrderNr" = t."OrderNr";
```

If you want to use the `USING` clause (which I would not recommend), you don't specify a condition but only the column name:

```
SELECT "OrderNr"
FROM public."Export" e
  LEFT JOIN public."Temp" t USING ("OrderNr");
```

Usually the `public` schema is in the [search path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) so you can exclude it:

```
SELECT e."OrderNr"
FROM "Export" e
  LEFT JOIN "Temp" t ON e."OrderNr" = t."OrderNr";
```

Comment: I second the remark that `USING` should be avoided.  It saves a few key strokes, but has limited functionality, and can introduce unexpected behaviour when joining multiple tables.